# IOS Sqlite Database - Retriving batch by batch records

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 database in my project. for that I can retrive the data from the Database using following query "select * from tablename"..

But I want to take the hundred sequence records from the database, like If I scroll the UITableView based on the I want to take 100 100 records.

I have tried the following things,
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date DESC LIMIT 100; - It retrives only 100 records.When I scroll the table i want to fetch the next 100 records and show it.

Is it possible to do it

Please Guide me.

Comment: Add the `OFFSET #` clause to the end of the query. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the [`OFFSET` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby), but this would still force the database to compute all the records that you're skipping over, so it would become inefficient for a larger table.

What you should do is to save the last `record_date` value of the previous page, and continue with the following ones:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE record_date < ?
ORDER BY record_date DESC
LIMIT 100
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor for details.